# Unity Facebook SDK Post Animated GIF

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, gif

I am trying to post an animated GIF file located in my computer on Facebook using the Unity Facebook SDK and FB.API. The code looks like this:

```
WWWForm formData = new WWWForm();
formData.AddField("description", "my description");
formData.AddBinaryData("file", gifContent, "gif_name");
FB.API("/me/videos", HttpMethod.POST, PostCallback, formData);
```

When `PostCallback` is called, the `IGraphResult` object in the parameter looks like this:

[image]
According to Facebook documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/video-uploads) the format `.gif` is supported and the image should have an aspect ratio of 9x16 or 16x9.

My `gifContent` is a `bytes array` that I read from a `.gif` file and the resolution of the file is 480x270. The size of the file could vary between 2-5MB all the way to 45-50MB (for testing purpose).

My Facebook SDK version is 7.9.0.

Note that the reason why I am trying to upload it as a video, is because I read somewhere that GIF are meant to be uploaded as videos, but for the record, I tried with `/me/photos` too before I tried with videos.

**UPDATE**:

This is the proper documentation link that shows GIF as a valid format (apologies for the mistake): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/video-uploads

Comment: The explanation of the error code on that page links to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/videos#Creating, and there it does _not_ list GIF as a valid format ... I’d perhaps file a bug report, and ask them for clarification whether you can use GIF as a video upload source or not, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: (Found [a bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/275717789611333/) saying that videos must be longer than one second; they are talking about mp4 video and the info from the video meta data there, but perhaps the same restriction applies when using a GIF as source …?)

Comment: Please check my update. I apologize for posting the wrong link. You are right, that link doesn't mention GIF as a valid format. Check the updated link please. Thanks.

Comment: That’s still the same link, I don’t think you got what I was trying to say - in a _different place_ of the documentation, specifically about uploading videos to pages (which I assume is what you’re doing here), it does _not_ list GIF as a valid format, it just lists a bunch of others. And since the documentation gives such contradictory info, my suggestion to file a bug report and ask for clarification under which circumstances/where/if at all you can use GIF as a video source ...

Comment: I undestand your suggestion. I just updated because I am sure I saw a list that included GIF as a valid format. But it might be a good idea to report a bug since, as you said, there is inconsistent docs.

Comment: By the way `gif` IS in that list, is the 11th element between `flv` and `m2ts`. Unless somehow I am being redirected to a different page.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/page/videos?locale=en_US does not mention "gif" there, and [ctrl]+[f] does not find it in that whole page either. _“We support the following formats for uploaded videos: 3g2, 3gp, 3gpp, asf, avi, dat, divx, dv, f4v, flv, m2ts, m4v, mkv, mod, mov, mp4, mpe, mpeg, mpeg4, mpg, mts, nsv, ogm, ogv, qt, tod, ts, vob, wmv.”_ is what that page contains, for me. (Going back to older API versions doesn’t seem to list gif there either; not sure if maybe one of the localized versions of that page contain different info.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posting this for future references.

It turns out that this issue was cause by a very stupid mistake that I made. The reason why I was getting the "invalid format" error in Unity is because the filename that I was passing to the `FB.API` method was missing the `.gif` extension (I didn't realized about this for quite some time).

The reason why this was hard to detect, is because although my example shows hard-coded string, in my real code I used a variable that came as the function parameter for the file name.

So instead of this:

`formData.AddBinaryData("file", gifContent, gifNameVariable);`

I did this:

`formData.AddBinaryData("file", gifContent, gifNameVariable + ".gif");`